# inverse via functional calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

Let $H$ be a positive definit self-adjoint operator. Can someone explain to me why $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-tH}dt}=H^{-1}?$$ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A = \int_0^\infty e^{-tH}dt$. It suffices to show that $AH = HA = I$ (if $H$ is an operator over a finite-dimensional space, it suffices to show that $HA = I$) where $I$ is the identity operator.

We have
$$
HA = H \int_0^\infty e^{-tH}dt = \int_0^\infty He^{-tH}dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}[-e^{-tH}]\,dt\\
= e^{-(0)H} - \lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-tH} = I - O = I.
$$
We can similarly show that $AH = I$.

Comment: I'd be interested in a clear explanation as to why $AH = I$ fails in the case that $H$ is not invertible.

Comment: I've figured out the answer to my comment: if $H$ is not invertible, then the integral that defines $A$ fails to converge.

Comment: Any idea on this prime number problem :-

Comment: What means that $H$ is not invertible here? $H$ not being bijective?

Comment: @S Yes, $H$ not being invertible is equivalent to $H$ not being bijective

Answer (score 2):

This is not a proof of the fact, but you might find it more intuitive by considering what would happen with a simple number $h$ rather than a matrix $H$. In this case 
$$\int e^{-th} dt = -\frac{e^{-th}}{h} = -h^{-1}e^{-th}$$ 
Then 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-th} dt = lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^x e^{-th} dt = lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (-h^{-1}e^{-xh} - (-h^{-1}e^{-0h})) = h^{-1}$$ 
So the situation with the matrix matches what would happen with a number.

Comment: They’re talking about a problem in greater generality than just matrices, let alone numbers.

Comment: @cmk I know, I was just showing how it matched the version with numbers, but I guess I should have used the word "operator" instead of "matrix."

Comment: @cmk: this is a good answer if one knows Functional Calculus and/or the Spectral Theorem.

Comment: Right, but the problem is to show that the result holds for operators (again, not just matrices). The whole point of functional calculus is to get anologues of statements which are true for basic functions for functions of (potentially unbounded) operators. So, showing it holds for just numbers isn’t necessarily that helpful.